# Add horizon line and grid lines to render image

Tags: rendering

Can anyone tell me how to make grid lines and a horizon line show when I render from Blender?  I am running version 2.82 and I can find no toggle for these.  I do NOT have any drop down that says "Overlays".  In the top right corner I have something that says "Options."  I am new to Blender.  I have been trying to change the background color and toggle grid lines and a horizon line on for about 5 days with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe show us  a capture  of your 3D view? (reduce the size of the window to give a reasonable size image, but not so far as to conceal any headers you _do_ have)

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are looking for does not exist, The laziest solution would be to just create a plane and sub-divde it a few times and apply a wireframe modifier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to enable them for normal render like you say but there are ways to get around it. Like you can recreate them as 3d models. (edges with wireframe modifier)
Or you can render viewport it self from top left just by clicking: view and then sellect you viewport render preference.